# CocoaPod issue with test target

Tags: ios, testing, swift, dependencies, cocoapods

I have a helper class (`GoogleHelper`) in swift that uses the Google finance API where I use `AFNetworking` for Google API call. `AFNetworking` is imported using cocoa pods.

I need to test the `GoogleHelper` and need mocking.

For mocking to work, I have to add the `GoogleHelper` file to test target as well. and redefine a mock class in the test class.

```
class MockGoogleHelper: GoogleHelper {
    override func getSymbol(text: String) -> String {
        return "symbol"
    }
}
```

The issue is that the test target has compiling issues with `AFNetwork`. I added the header files and the compiled pod library manually to the test target but the issue persist.

I have two questions?

1. how to make the cocoa pods add the dependency to the test target. I have used `linked_with` in my pod file but no luck
2. If there is any hint on the way I am setting my test wrong let me know as I think when I test my helper class it should not depend on the `AFNetworking` but I am not sure how to eliminate the dependency.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things you should do to get it to work:

1. add the test target to your pod file e.g. linked_with 'myprj', 'myprjTests'
2. in project/info/configuration for both debug and release select Pods.debug or Pods.release respectively.
3. you need to bridge your library if project is on swift and the library imported with cocoa pods is in objective c. to do so just try to add an objective c file to your test files and Xcode will automatically add the bridging header to your project.